# Define a 4-digit number and a Boolean variable that stores if the number is "capicúa" (it reads the same from back to front as from front to back)

Tags: python

I am very new to programming in Python, and I came across this problem. What I thought about doing is to make the user input a number, than use an If Else Statement to determine if it is "capicúa" or not. And finally, print whether it is "capicúa" or not. But I have no idea of how to write a line of code that can check what the digits of the number are. So, does anyone have any suggestion.

P.S. If you think that what I am attempting to do is too complex for an absolute beginner, it could be that I misunderstood what I am supposed to do. In case that you are wandering, I translated this from Spanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get digits as `str` then use `[::-1]` and reverse digits and check they are same or not:

```
>>> digits = input('Enter Number:')
>>> digits == digits[::-1]
```

Output:

```
Enter Number:2332
True

Enter Number:1234
False
```

Comment: You know, I deliberately avoided writing this to try get the OP to do it themselves (and because string slicing is kind of harder for newbies).  It's how I'd do it, ofc

Answer (score 0):

Handle the number as a *string*, which will let you iterate over it like this:

```py
a = "123978"
for digit in a:
    print(digit)
```

To get the digits in a string backwards, we can use `reversed`:

```
for digit in reversed(a):
    print(digit)
```

And lastly, to iterate two things at once we can use zip:

```py
for normal, reverse in zip(a, reversed(a)):
    print(normal, reverse)
```

Or we can use indexes:

```py
reverse = list(reversed(a)) # the cast to list is important
# otherwise we have an iterable which can't be indexed
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i], reverse[i])
```

You now have all the tools you need to solve the problem: have a go :)